# forEach index to count from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

Given the code below:

```
pdfDocs.forEach((pdf, index) => {
 console.log(`Printing pack ${index} of ${pdfDocs.length}`);
})
```

which outputs:

```
Printing pack 0 of 2
Printing pack 1 of 2
```

Is there are a way to start counting at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Did you search on the internet ? there are plenty of answers already.

Comment: Try `console.log(`Printing pack ${index + 1} of ${pdfDocs.length}`);`

Comment: Yes I did, but I was getting other approaches of loops and other languages. Maybe I was googling the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Simply add +1 to the index value, like following.

```
pdfDocs.forEach((pdf, index) => {
    console.log(`Printing pack ${index+1} of ${pdfDocs.length}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Array start at 0, so that's normal it start at 0.

The length correspond to amount of item in it. So the only way is to do :

```
pdfDocs.forEach((pdf, index) => {
 console.log(`Printing pack ${index + 1} of ${pdfDocs.length}`);
})
```

Start at one, will make you just loop on the item 1, and that's finish. So do:

```
1 of 2
```